# Exactly How Do We Export And Then Import Parse Objects With Relations?

Tags: import, export, parse-platform, relation

I want to archive my Parse database. It has a class with a column that is a many-to-many relation. When I export I get a _Join table file. But I can not find any explanation how to import the _Join table file so that I can restore the column data for the objects. How do I import the _join files?